# How can I get to Mike Brant's grave?

Tags: public-transport, israel, cemeteries

[Mike Brant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Brant), the famous singer is buried in Haifa. According to Wikipedia the cemetery is called "Camp David".

Could someone tell me where exactly it is and how I can get there from the German Colony. I don't have a private car at my disposal.

Comment: I had gone from Canada to Haifa’s Jewish cemetery, I followed the above instructions by following the description of the area where I could find Mike Brant’s grave.
I was walking around for 4 hours in the blistering Sun, trying to locate the grave.
Unfortunately, and sadly, I couldn’t find the grave.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mike Brant is buried in the *Sde Yehoshua* Jewish Cemetery in Haifa, also called *Mahane (camp) David* or *Neve David* after the neighborhood it located next to it. The Cemetery can be seen [on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@32.8022894,34.9658817,17z). There are two bus stations, one beneath it and one above it, different buses go to each station, so you should decide what entrance you need before. The location of the stations is:

[image: The location of the stations]

The red circle is the above station and the blue, the below.

To find out what buses go there you can check the [Egged site](https://mslworld.egged.co.il/eggedtimetable/WebForms/wfrmMain.aspx?width=1024&company=1&language=en&state). The station in the German colony is called *German Colony: Kiryat Eliyahu, Sderot Ben Gu...* (the main street) or *German Colony: Yitskhak Sadeh*.

The station above (red) the cemetery is called *Kfar Samir Cemetery: Military Cemetery*, as can be seen from the picture, there are several stations there, and you don't need the military cemetery, but the civilian cemetery, which is the next station **after** the military cemetery, you can ask the driver to tell you what station you need.

The station below (blue) the cemetery is called *The Old Cemetery: Sderot ha-Hagana*, there is only one station there.

I could find the exact location of the grave in the cemetery however, only a picture of the grave:

[image: pic1]

<sup>([source](https://www.tapuz.co.il/#148682328))</sup>

There are more pictures of the grave online. Sadly I couldn't find the exact location of the grave, only that it's located near a wall, but it isn't clear what wall it is, and if it's a wall separating the different cemeteries, or a bounding wall.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Just one question about the bus driver? Do you think he will understand some Russian or English?

Comment: Most probably that he or someone on the bus will understand. If you want, you can write on a note " בית הקברות היהודי", which means the Jewish Cemetery and show to him, I'll write it again alone in the next comment, or ask the Hotel staff/people you stay with to write down what you need.

Comment: בית הקברות היהודי

Comment: Excellent! By the way, you EGGED link doesn't work properly. I will fix it

Comment: @IanLudr, if you do visit the grave, please add its exact location inside the cemetery to help other people who will look it in the future.

Comment: If you create an account at FindAGrave.com, you can "suggest an edit" and put in the latitude and longitude and/or the section/row/plot number.